# getChildrenCategories only includes categories with Include in navigation set to yes

Tags: category

I want to display the child categories of a category and I want to display them in the order they're in in the admin panel. I've read a lot about it and the simplest way seems to be to use *getChildrenCategories* as that returns the children in the right order.

However, I've found this only returns categories with **Include in navigation** set to **yes** whereas all the child categories have this set to no in my case.

I've tracked this down to *_loadNodes* in *flat.php*. I've included the relevant code from it below and you can see the hard coded where statement in the penultimate line.

My question is simply how can I stop this? Is there a simple way?

Thanks

```
protected function _loadNodes($parentNode = null, $recursionLevel = 0, $storeId = 0, $onlyActive = true)
{
    $_conn = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $startLevel = 1;
    $parentPath = '';
    if ($parentNode instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
        $parentPath = $parentNode->getPath();
        $startLevel = $parentNode->getLevel();
    } elseif (is_numeric($parentNode)) {
        $selectParent = $_conn->select()
            ->from($this->getMainStoreTable($storeId))
            ->where('entity_id = ?', $parentNode)
            ->where('store_id = ?', $storeId);
        $parentNode = $_conn->fetchRow($selectParent);
        if ($parentNode) {
            $parentPath = $parentNode['path'];
            $startLevel = $parentNode['level'];
        }
    }
    $select = $_conn->select()
        ->from(
            array('main_table' => $this->getMainStoreTable($storeId)),
            array('entity_id',
                new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.' . $_conn->quoteIdentifier('name')),
                new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.' . $_conn->quoteIdentifier('path')),
                'is_active',
                'is_anchor'))

        ->where('main_table.include_in_menu = ?', '1')
        ->order('main_table.position');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: rewrite or observer.

**Rewrite:**

The rewrite DOM structure for this is a bit tricky because it is a resource model:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <flat>Your_Module_Model_Resource_Flat</flat><!-- for example -->
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Then in the class file for `Your_Module_Model_Resource_Flat` you would extend from the core flat category resource model and override this method, changing what you need to change.

---

**Observer:**

Register an observer in the frontend for the `catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before` event in the frontend, which you can see is dispatched just below the code you referenced. In fact it is preceded by a note stating, "Allow extensions to modify select (e.g. add custom category attributes to select)". In your observing method, you will need to manipulate the select object which is passed in; I have untested peudo-y code here:

```
public function allowExcludedCategories($o)
{
    $select = $o->getSelect();
    $oWhere  = $select->getPart(Varien_Db_Select::WHERE);
    $select->setPart(Varien_Db_Select::WHERE,array_shift($oWhere));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @benmarks. I don't really want to rewrite it as it seems to be used elsehwere so I could add a new set of methods I guess. I've not done anything with observers before so I don't know if I can use that to provide a one-off change where I want it, I'll look into it.

Comment: I've gone down the observer route but it always run so now my main menu includes everything. I need it only to fire for a particular call to _getChildrenCategories_. Is there a way of doing this (or having my observer know why it was triggered)? PS Your code was very close :o) but left a where clause starting with an ADD (I used a substr to remove it).

Comment: You *could* make your observer a singleton and have it keep track of how many times it's been invoked. This is of course brittle as hell. Perhaps it's time to duplicate the `_loadNodes()` logic elsewhere and tie it into the context where you need it.

Comment: I just came across the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340982/how-do-i-save-value-in-my-own-session-variable-in-magento. So I've simply set a session variable before I call _getChildrenCategories_, check if it's set in the observer, run the observer if so and clear it there too. Happy days!